# Is it possible to order cipher suites from server side in Java?

Tags: java, ssl, serversocket, ssl-security

In [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/SSLParameters.html#setUseCipherSuitesOrder(boolean)) stated, that:

> `public final void setUseCipherSuitesOrder​(boolean honorOrder)`
>
> Sets whether the local cipher suites preference should be honored.
>
> Parameters:
>       honorOrder - whether local cipher suites order in #getCipherSuites should be honored during SSL/TLS/DTLS handshaking.

The order of cipher suits:

```
String[] cs = new String[]{
 "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
 "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
 "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
  };
```

If I set socket parameters like:

```
SSLServerSocket.getSSLParameters().setUseCipherSuitesOrder(true);
SSLServerSocket.setEnabledProtocols(....);
SSLServerSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(cs);
```

by using `# nmap -sT  -p 465 host_address --script ssl-enum-ciphers.nse` the result is:

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
465/tcp open  smtps
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 4096) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|_  least strength: A
```

Cipher order is still defined by client: `cipher preference: client`. Is it possible to set priority by server? Using JDK 12.

Comment: Well, the API says *should* which is not a strict *must*. Implementing classes could argument, they don't have to. This might be a reason that could explain your observation(s).

Comment: Thanks for the nmap snippet! This streamlined my debugging and working things out process quite a bit :).

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour seems to have changed since JDK 12. At least with JDK 17 the order proposed by the server seems to be preferred by default. Anyway, the correct way to use the API would be

```
    SSLParameters parameters = serverSocket.getSSLParameters();
    parameters.setUseCipherSuitesOrder(true);
    serverSocket.setSSLParameters(parameters);
```

The crucial part is to call `setSSLParameters()`. Where you get the `SSLParameters` object from is secondary.